# [XSS]Expressjs prevent run script form POST request

Tags: javascript, security, express, xss

I'm new to ExpressJs. I have a question about posted javascript

```
app.get('/nothing/:code',function(req, res) {
    var code = req.params.code;
    res.send(code)
});
```

If I POST javascript tag, It would run. Is there way to prevent that?

Comment: You would need to sanitize the string - change `<` to `%3C` and `>` to `%3E`

Comment: @JonathanBrooks How to do it?

Comment: Why not just restrict the values to say letters or numbers, and then reject reuqests containing special characters etc. (input validation) ?

Comment: @Erlend That's ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possible [HTML sanitizers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_sanitization) out there (as [simple search on NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=sanitizer) will give you a listing that you can use in your nodejs code).

The most simple would be to simply use the built in "escape" function, but that won't stop many XSS attacks.

```
app.get('/nothing/:code',function(req, res) {
   var code = escape(req.params.code);
   res.send(code)
});
```

A better solution would be to use a library designed for this purpose. For example if you used the santizier library ([Google Caja's HTML sanitizer packaged for node](https://github.com/theSmaw/Caja-HTML-Sanitizer)):

```
var sanitizer = require('sanitizer');
...
app.get('/nothing/:code',function(req, res) {
   var code = sanitizer.sanitize(req.params.code);
   res.send(code)
});
```

Comment: You have given here example for request param, similarly can we do it for request body.